# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libdeflate.so

Tags: cmd, conda

[image]I am a mac user with operating system, macOS Mojave 10.14.6. I have installed bcftools in my conda environment py3.9 (Python 3.9).
The following code is my installing command line:

```
conda install -c bioconda bcftools
```

but when I try to use it, the shell told me there is something wrong with it.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libdeflate.so
Referenced from: /opt/anaconda3/envs/py3.9/bin/bcftools
Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

when I went the path (/opt/anaconda3/envs/py3.9/bin/bcftools), I found there is only a binary file.
I hope that someone can help me, thanks!

Comment: libdeflate should be here --> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MaA4JS6Kqnu9QQAP7k6fNyMN9aLJrIN5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: conda install -c "bioconda/label/cf201901" bcftools

Answer (score 1):

Bioconda has [very specific channel requirements](http://bioconda.github.io/user/install.html#set-up-channels), namely, it builds packages using Conda Forge builds, not Anaconda (**defaults**). The correct *ad hoc* installation command for Bioconda packages is:

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge -c bioconda -c defaults bcftools
```

However, if you have an Anaconda **base** (as opposed to Miniforge), it is usually not a good idea to prioritize the **conda-forge** channel when installing in **base** (can lead to lots of channel switching and long solves). Instead, create a new environment and configure it to use the correct channels:

```bash
# create new environment
conda create -n my_env

# activate environment
conda activate my_env

# set channels for environment
conda config --env --add channels defaults
conda config --env --add channels bioconda
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge

# no need to use ad hoc `-c` flags
conda install bcftools
```

Comment: I think this is not the issue of channels, since I have all these channels in my environment.

Comment: @KenHsu I'm thinking that installing into an existing Anaconda environment might have some of your dependencies satisfied with builds that are technically incompatible. Does creating a new environment work?

Comment: @KenHsu Actually, `libdeflate` used to be provided by **bioconda**, so I suspect the underlying issue is that by doing `-c bioconda` instead of `-c conda-forge -c bioconda` you are prioritizing old versions of `libdeflate` rather than the Conda Forge version that is `bcftools` is likely using.

Comment: No, new environment did not solve this problem

Comment: I can download it, but i cannot use it @@. I add a picture of my terminal now.

Comment: pls refer to --> https://github.com/samtools/bcftools/issues/1643

Comment: https://github.com/samtools/bcftools/issues/1434#issuecomment-785804721

Comment: And try the third command on this webpage --> https://anaconda.org/bioconda/bcftools

Comment: conda install -c "bioconda/label/cf201901" bcftools

Comment: @envs_h_gang_5 I wouldn’t recommend that last one with the label - unless you can qualify why a label is needed, they should almost never be recommended as they have very specific consequences users typically do not need.

Comment: Also, those links are all examples of improper mixing of channels - e.g., advice is still to follow my answer.